# Matching substring to user input

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a user input string and on basis of that, I execute case statement of the switch.For example, if user types string hello is taken to case hello.Everything works fine but when I put string ='**shimla weather**' it takes it to 'hi' because that matches first.
How can I better implement this?

```
var string = 'shimla weather';
var substring = ['hi', 'hello', 'weather', 'joke'];
console.log(substring);
var doubles = substring.map(function(x) {
    if(string.includes(x)){
      expression = x;
    }
  });     
  console.log(expression);          
  switch(expression) {
    case 'hi':
    case 'hello'
        console.log('hello');
        break;
    case 'weather':
    console.log('weather');
        break;
    case 'joke':
        console.log('joe');
        break;
    default:

}
```

Comment: One way could be to sort the `case`s from the longest to the shortest word.

Comment: You don't describe the desired behaviour. What do you want to happen if there are multiple matches?

Comment: Yes the problem arises in case of  multiple matches@Marty. I want to handle that .

Comment: Handle it by doing what? Do you want to throw an error, trigger all matches, trigger the longest one, trigger the shortest one, trigger the one that comes last, or do something completely different?

Comment: Like if someone says shimla weather it means they are asking for weather so case weather should execute, not the case 'hi'
@Marty

Comment: do you want to match the complete word or any substring within statement will work?

Comment: As above it sounds like you're asking to match whole words only, is that right?

Comment: Yes @Marty. trigger the response on the basis of user query to most aptly matched substring.

Comment: Matching should be like if someone says shimla weather it means they are asking for weather so case weather should execute, not the case 'hi @AnshumanJaiswal

Comment: To check if something contains a whole word only you could use something like `string.split(/\s+/).includes(substr)`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to focus on word rather than substrings within word, you can do following:

```
var string = 'shimla weather';
var substring = ['hi', 'hello', 'weather', 'joke'];
var splittedWords = string.split(/\s+/);
var isWordFound = false;
substring.map(function(x) {
    var index = splittedWords.indexOf(x);
    if(index != -1){
      isWordFound = true;
      word = splittedWords[index];
      matchFound(word);
    }
}); 

if(!isWordFound) {
  // do whatever you want
}       

function matchFound(word) {
    switch(word) {
        case 'hi':
        case 'hello':
            console.log('hello');
            break;
        case 'weather':
        console.log('weather');
            break;
        case 'joke':
            console.log('joe');
            break;
        default:
    }
}
```

Comment: What if no matched entry comes this function wont execute default in that case@Anshuman Jaiswal
For ex: string ='h'

Comment: edited answer, now if complete word is not found you can do whatever you want in `if(!isWordF)` block